Rails controller raises NameError: uninitialized constant - no issue from other directories
I seem to have run into a strange issue. I've got a Rails app set up with Sorbet. All of my type files are in their own directory under /app (autoloaded by default).
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── jobs
│   ├── mailers
│   ├── models
│   ├── services
│   ├── sorbet_types
│   │   └── types
│   │       ├── dto
│   │       ├── error_types
│   │       └── services
│   │           └── session
|   |                └── sign_up_params_type.rb

The sorbet_types directory houses additional directories and/or files. A particular type (the issue happens for any type)` is structured as follows:
module Types
  module Services
    module Session
      class UserSignUpParamsType < T::Struct
        const :email, String
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end

Interestingly enough, if I attempt to access this Type from a file in the services directory using Types::Services::Session::UserSignUpParamsType it works no problem (similar to all of the other types being successful from all other directories). However, when I'm attempting to use the above namespace path from within a controller, I get
NameError: uninitialized constant Types::Services::Session::UserSignUpParamsType.
Is there anything special I'm missing regarding this being in a controller? I've attempted to prefix with leading :: as well, but no such luck.
Edited to add:

This is Rails 7.2.1 w/ Ruby 3.3.0
I am able to get this to work if I require_relative


@engineersmnky here's the tree for the sorbet_types directory. The sorbet_types directory is getting autoloaded since it's in the app directory and calling it works from everywhere but the controllers directory
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── jobs
│   ├── mailers
│   ├── models
│   ├── services
│   ├── sorbet_types
│   │   └── types
│   │       ├── dto
│   │       ├── error_types
│   │       └── services
│   │           └── session
|   |                └── sign_up_params_type.rb


@engineersmnky Updated the question, thanks

Zietwerk expects the file name to match the defined class name, so your issue is the file name is sign_up_params_type.rb but your class name is UserSignUpParamsType either change the file to user_sign_up_params_type.rb or change the class to SignUpParamsType.

@engineersmnky just updated the file name to user_sign_up_params_type.rb and that was it. Typos, it's always typos. If you would like to make your comment an answer, I'll mark it as the answer
